# set shadow of recyclerview paceholder's bottom in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, shadow

[image]

Hi, i am implementing this type of UI with `RecyclerView` and

```
addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(-80));
```

for overlapping gap between two images.
So, can you suggest me how to implement shadow between two `View`

Comment: You could use CardView as parent element for shadowing

Comment: Use CardView and setElevation as per your need.

Comment: there is no such constructor, see: [DividerItemDecoration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/DividerItemDecoration.html) docs

Comment: i am not used card view

Comment: getItemOffsets used for overlapping gap @pskink

Comment: i know what `getItemOffsets` is for

Comment: then suggest me what i do for shadow?

Comment: `android.graphics.BlurMaskFilter`

Comment: how to make item ui like this , sir ?